# Get the connection associated with an Atmosphere @ManagedService message

Tags: java, uuid, atmosphere

In [this example](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere-samples/blob/master/samples/chat/src/main/java/org/atmosphere/samples/chat/Chat.java), is there a way to modify this method

```java
@org.atmosphere.config.service.Message(encoders = {JacksonEncoder.class}, decoders = {JacksonDecoder.class})
public Message onMessage(Message message) throws IOException {
    logger.info("{} just send {}", message.getAuthor(), message.getMessage());
    return message;
}
```

so I can get the UUID (available in the `AtmosphereResource` upon connection) so that I know which connection the message is coming from? I have tried adding an `AtmosphereResource` parameter, but it doesn't work (no message is received).

Answer (score 4):

Actually, an `AtmosphereResource` parameter can be added to `onMessage`. It must be the first parameter. (I tried to add it as the second parameter and it didn't work.)

So the method in the question can be changed to this:

```javascript
@org.atmosphere.config.service.Message(encoders = {JacksonEncoder.class}, decoders = {JacksonDecoder.class})
public Message onMessage(AtmosphereResource r, Message message) throws IOException {

    // TODO: Look up any info associated with the connection using r.uuid().

    logger.info("{} just send {}", message.getAuthor(), message.getMessage());
    return message;
}
```